# Double divided with double = Integer?

Tags: c#, double

I don't know much about C#, but I was trying to do a simple division here and I think I'm going mad, because nothing works.

Ok, so explain to me why this works:

```
            double minimum = 2.00 / 100.00;
            Console.WriteLine(minimum); // displays "0,02"
```

But this doesn't work?:

```
      double result;
      if(Double.TryParse(returnTextBox.Text, out result))
        {
            double minimum = (double)result / 100.00;
            Console.WriteLine(minimum); // displays "2"
        }
```

I tried casting (double) on everything possible. Also without casting it. Seems to always show 2. I feel like im missing something important, I just can't see it.

Comment: And what text is in the `returnTextBox`?

Comment: What is the content of returnTextBox.Text?

Comment: I've got "2.00" in the textbox

Comment: Have you checked the value of result?

Comment: Yes, your locale uses the comma as separator not the point.

Comment: It seems your culture uses comma as the decimal point character. try 2,00 instead

Comment: yes...exactly as @Bizhan said...your culture uses comma instead of dot for decimal type.

Comment: _if (Double.TryParse(returnTextBox, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result))_

Comment: Yep. It was the damn decimal point that should've been a comma. I spent 30 minutes on this....

Answer (score 1):

The solution was this:

```
Double.TryParse(returnTextBox.Text, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result)
```

Thanks everyone!